# What is the best practice of managing realm instance in Clean Architecture?

Tags: android, realm, clean-architecture

My project using clean architecture. In this situation, the UI layer is separate from Domain layer. So I think it would be better the UI layer doesn't own realm instance. As realm's doc recommend managing the realm instance in Activity's lifecycle, how should I deal with the realm instance then?

To be more clear, my project is too heavy to change all objects extends `RealmObject`. So I use separate object to persistent data. When the api call finish, a business object convert to a realm object, opposite when query from realm. I create the method like this:

```
public void insert(T object){
    final Realm realm = RealmProvider.getRealm();
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(createRealmObject(object));
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            realm.close();
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            realm.close();
        }
    });
}
```

Actually, it works fine. But below I don't know how to handle closing realm instance.

```
public Observable<T> queryAsync(Condition<? extends RealmObject> condition) {
    final Realm realm = RealmProvider.getRealm();
    return condition.getQuery(realm).findFirstAsync()
            .asObservable()
            .filter(new Func1<RealmObject, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(RealmObject realmObject) {
                    return realmObject.isLoaded();
                }
            })
            .map(new Func1<RealmObject, T>() {
                @Override
                public T call(RealmObject realmObject) {
                    return createObjectFromRealm(realmObject);
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a clean separation between UI and database layers in your code, and you want to abstract away your database logic so that ideally your activity can call database layer without knowing how that layer is implemented, then Realm is probably not what you're looking for.

Realm objects are tied to realm instances which means that if you retrieve an object from a realm instance and then close that instance (which you must), you can no longer use the object. Which defeats the entire purpose of using Realm.

If you are going to use Realm, you should keep the realm logic closely tied to your activities/services etc, and don't try to hide it in a separate layer, so that you have full control over it.

---

```
        .map(new Func1<RealmObject, T>() {
            @Override
            public T call(RealmObject realmObject) {
                Object o = createObjectFromRealm(realmObject);
                realm.close();
                return o;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I update some detail above. I understand in this way, it abandon most amazing advantages of realm. But the project's architecture is determinate, so, is it possible to use realm in this condition?

Comment: @ZeatualChang I imagine `call` is the last function in the chain so you can close the realm there, see the edit. It may work

Comment: I have tried this, but rx operators works on the thread witch realm asynchronous query works on. It is a different thread from the one realm instance is opened.

Comment: @ZeatualChang try making a looper on the 'normal' thread and in `call` run code on the 'normal' thread by referencing that looper

Answer (score 0):

One of the major aspect of a clean architecture is, isolation of major libraries (i.e. Realm). Since Realm, RealmObject, RealmResults are not accessible outside of the Thread they are created in, it makes it even more important to keep Realm & Realm related calculations isolated from rest of the code.

You are using RxJava in your queryAsync() method, and at the same time you are using executeTransactionAsync() method, which defies the whole purpose of using RxJava. You could have done like this,

```
public void insert(T object){
    final Realm realm = RealmProvider.getRealm();
    realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> 
    realm1.copyToRealmOrUpdate(createRealmObject(object)));
    realm.close();
}
```

In a good Architecture, for each jsonModel class there should be a corresponding realmModel class & a DAO (Data Access Object). DAO class must take jsonModel as argument and must return jsonModel as result. All Realm related operations must be restricted within the DAO file, that way none of the code other than DAO and realmModel knows about Realm.

Here is an article about Realm best practices with a good architechture https://medium.com/@Viraj.Tank/realm-integration-in-android-best-practices-449919d25f2f

Also a sample project demonstrating Integration of Realm on Android with MVP(Model View Presenter), RxJava, Retrofit, Dagger, Annotations & Testing.
https://github.com/viraj49/Realm_android-injection-rx-test

Comment: What features of realm are you giving up on when using this approach?

Comment: AFAI none, you can do all Realm operations without missing out on anything, Its main focus is to keep all Realm stuff away from rest of the code.

Comment: @Tim, After a long discussion and some more findings, it turns out you miss out a few Realm features when use isolation approach. e.g. Realm's auto-update of the view when RealmObject is modified.

Comment: Exactly. I find that a big disadvantage

Comment: True, but on the other hand you have to perform Realm operations on MainThread, which seems even bigger threat to me as of now.

Comment: @Viraj Tank great article. Actually, I have solved this problem. I made a mistake above when discussing with @Tim Castelinjns. I can close the realm instance in `onCompelete()` and `onError()`. They are on the same thread with calling method `findFirstAsync()`. And I do not think using `executeTransactionAsync()` defies the purpose of rxjava. Actually, I have two method for each operation. One synchronous and the other asynchronous. Using `executeTransactionAsync()` cause I don't need to observe the transaction. But still it moves the WRITE operation away from main thread.

Comment: Thanks, I agree, If you are performing rx operations on mainThread then makes sense to use Async methods from Realm. My initial isolation approach works well with production codes without changing much but you miss out many Realm features. Shortly I will publish another approach which focuses on being able to use all Realm features with clean architecture.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the discussion earlier, It inspired me to create a different approach. Please have a look at this https://medium.com/@Viraj.Tank/deep-integration-of-realm-in-android-production-code-part-2-with-mvp-4cf44ab6289d and let me know what you guys think.